# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} x^2+4y = 5$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} (x^2+4y) =5$.

I tried proving it by estimating $|x^2+4y-5|$
i.e $\leq |x^2-1|+4|y-1|$
To prove $|x-1|< \delta ,$ $|y-1|<\delta $ implies $|x^2-1|+4|y-1| < \epsilon$...
Kindly help me prove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|x^{2}-1|=|x-1| [|x-1|+2] <3|x-1|$ if $|x-1|<1$.

Comment: so if we choose $\delta < min\{1,\epsilon/4\}$ then we are done... It's so easy... Thanks